# What will happen if I delete node_modules folder?

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

I'm getting an error after installing any package via `npm`. Every time I serve my application through `ng serve`, it gives me an error saying `Error: Type [packageName] does not have 'ɵmod' property.` What should I do?

I guess if I delete my `node_modules` folder and re-create it via `npm install` command, it would be resolved.

Anybody can suggest if I delete `node_modules` folder and after re-creating it, will I get all the already installed packages back in the same way they were just before deleting?

Comment: The solution to your problem is exactly what you have mentioned, delete the nodemodules folder, close any open editors and run `npm install`

Comment: YES, you will get back all the packages listed in your package.json file.

Comment: delete your `node_modules` folder and before `npm i` you should delete the `[packageName]` from `package.json` . or you can do simple : `npm uninstall [packageName]`

Answer (score 6):

*if i delete node_modules folder and after re-creating it, will i get all the already installed packages back in the same way they were just before?*

**answer is yes.**

or you can do it with

```
npm ci
```

its faster and do the same job.

**but what if problem is with your package-lock?**

your team commited package-lock.json and in merge or somehow its not the correct.

here you need to **remove package-lock too.**

now getting packages same as they were beforedepends on your package.json.

look at this package.json

```
{
  "name": "awesome-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
   .
   .
   .
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.8.1"
   },
}
```

every time i run npm install, because of "^", npm looks for last angular release which match 1.X.X version and update your package to that version.

[image]

if we see angular versions on npm website, angular released 1.8.2 one month after 1.8.1 .
so this depends on when you are installing and how did you specify version range.

[read more about npm flags](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver)

Comment: Wouldn't recommend removing `package-lock.json` since that could really throw off versions for other dependencies as well. Instead, I would try re-installing the problematic dependency and maybe try resolving versioning problems individually.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing bad, you can easily delete it and then reinstall everything via

```
npm i
```

in console.
You can see here details about deleting it:https://medium.com/@MarkPieszak/how-to-delete-all-node-modules-folders-on-your-machine-and-free-up-hd-space-f3954843aeda

Answer (score 0):

node modules act as a library to the file which we have to use in the directory of the project. It simply provides all dependencies that are required to run a project but, package.json acts as an abstract layer that only holds the version of that dependencies, deleting node modules would not affect the package.json but the project still holds its version of the dependencies version. So if you want to use some other version of those dependencies Either delete the package.json and install all libraries of that project then delete node modules and then reinstall all (node modules)and make package.json again
by Command

`npm uninstall --save <package> name`

`npm  i`

`npm i <package name>`